# How to extract all elements from selector with attribute active to the last element

Tags: javascript, selector

I have a list of select options from 00h to 23h, this option is updated every hour and select the current hour and add `is-active` attribute, so I want to get all elements from this attribute to the last element
this is my code

```
<span class="jsx-674775893 option-text left">00</span>
<span class="jsx-674775893 option-text left">01</span>
.
.
<span class="jsx-674775893 option-text left is-active">18</span>
.
<span class="jsx-674775893 option-text left">22</span>
<span class="jsx-674775893 option-text left">23</span>
```

So for this example I want to get all elements selector from 18 to 23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the element with `is-active` *and* its following siblings, you can use a selector group with the element (`span.is-active` for example, or just `.is-active`) and its following siblings via `~` (`span.is-active, span.is-active ~ span`), the [general sibling combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#general-sibling-combinators).

In CSS:

```css
span.is-active, span.is-active ~ span {
    /*...*/
}
```

Or in a `querySelectorAll` call (either on the document or a containing element):

```js
const spans = document.querySelectorAll("span.is-active, span.is-active ~ span");
```

Example:

```js
const spans = document.querySelectorAll("span.is-active, span.is-active ~ span");
console.log(Array.from(spans, e => e.textContent));
```

```html
<span class="jsx-674775893 option-text left">00</span>
<span class="jsx-674775893 option-text left">01</span>

<span class="jsx-674775893 option-text left is-active">18</span>

<span class="jsx-674775893 option-text left">22</span>
<span class="jsx-674775893 option-text left">23</span>
```

I've used `span` there, but you don't have to if you want to be more open: `.is-active, .is-active ~ *` does just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [~ selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) will get the siblings after. And since you want to include the active element, you need to add that to the selector also with a comma so you can have both included in the result.

- `.option-text.is-active` Selects the active element
- `.option-text.is-active ~ .option-text` selects the siblings after the active element

```js
var elementWithSiblings = document.querySelectorAll(".option-text.is-active, .option-text.is-active ~ .option-text");
console.log(elementWithSiblings.length)
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="jsx-674775893 option-text left">00</span>
  <span class="jsx-674775893 option-text left">01</span>
  <span class="jsx-674775893 option-text left is-active">18</span>
  <span class="jsx-674775893 option-text left">22</span>
  <span class="jsx-674775893 option-text left">23</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try:

```
var elements = document.querySelector(".option-text");
```

Then you can use `elements.filter()` to filter for wanted elements